# how to print a text/plain document in CUPS printer without using raw option

Tags: linux, printing, cups

I am using a CUPs command to print the pages of documents,But it is printing all the pages ignoiring the pages option. After some  investigation I came to know raw option is overwriting the pages option , Please tell me how to print the pages without using raw option ,If I am not using this option , text file not supporting error is coming ,Here is my code :

```
system("lpr -P AFSCMSRPRNT3  -o pages=1,2,6  -o raw -T test_womargin abc.txt"
```

Answer (score 2):

Plain text files don't really specify how things should be printed, and thus aren't allowed.

Try to convert the text to any usable format first. There's a popular tool `a2ps` which should be available for every linux distribution in the world. Try that!

**EDIT** you seem to be confused by the word "convert":
What I meant is that instead of printing the text file, you print a postscript file generated form that; something that you can get by doing something like

```
a2ps -o temporaryoutput.ps input.txt
```

and then

```
lpr -P AFSCMSRPRNT3  -o pages=1,2,6 -T test_womargin temporaryoutput.ps
```

Comment: These files are dynamically creating, so I cannot change the format of file, moreover everything is working fine as of now, but problem with raw option, it is overwriting the pages what I have mentioned in command, it is printing all the pages

Comment: obviously then, you'll have to convert each file on the fly -- where's the problem wiht that?

Comment: Muller , Is any other way is there  without using file formatting conversion?, raw option is not allowing the filtering option..